# Comparing string prefixes in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

Groovy 2.4.x here. I have a method that takes two `Strings` and needs to do some analysis on them.

- If neither string ends with "`FIZZ`" or "`BUZZ`", then it should return `false`
- If only one string ends with either "`FIZZ`" or "`BUZZ`", then it should return `false`
- If both strings end with either "`FIZZ`" or "`BUZZ`", then we continue...

  - In this case, we want to extract the substring of both strings *before* "`FIZZ`"/"`BUZZ`" -> "prefixes"
  - We want to now simply compare both prefixes. If they are identical strings, return `true`; otherwise, `false`

Examples:

- "`foo`" & "`bar`" => `false` (because neither ends with "`FIZZ`" or "`BUZZ`")
- "`foo`" & "`barFIZZ`" => `false` (because only 1 ends with "`FIZZ`" or "`BUZZ`")
- "`fooFIZZ`" & "`barBUZZ`" => `false` (because "`foo`" != "`bar`")
- "`fooFIZZ`" & "`fooBUZZ`" => `true` (because "`foo`" == "`foo`")

Here's my best attempt:

```
class FizzBuzzMatcher {
    boolean matches(String left, String right) {
        boolean matches = false
        if(right.endsWith('FIZZ') || right.endsWith('BUZZ')) {
            String rightPrefix
            rightPrefix = right.subSequence(0, right.indexOf('FIZZ'))
            if(rightPrefix.isEmpty()) {
                rightPrefix = right.subSequence(0, right.indexOf('BUZZ'))
            }

            if(left.endsWith('FIZZ') || left.endsWith('BUZZ')) {
                String leftPrefix
                leftPrefix = left.subSequence(0, left.indexOf('FIZZ'))
                if(leftPrefix.isEmpty()) {
                    leftPrefix = left.subSequence(0, left.indexOf('BUZZ'))
                }

                if(leftPrefix == rightPrefix) {
                    matches = true
                }
            }
        }

        matches
    }
}
```

...but as you can see, this is kind of nasty. Any more elegant solution here? I'm open to OSS libs (Apache Commons, etc.).

Comment: The `xyz` outputs are confusing when it looks like it should be `false` and then `true`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a regexp :

```
​pattern = ~/(.*)(FIZZ|BUZZ)/

def matches(left, right) {
  def m1, m2
  return (m1 = (left =~ pattern)) && (m2 = (right =~ pattern)) 
    && (m1[0][1] == m2[0][1])
}
```

see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators for syntaxes on regexp operators

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B (+1) - can I assume that `m1` and `m2` are booleans and that `subprefix` returns a boolean as well?

Comment: m1 and m2 are instances of Matcher-s, the result of a match with a regexp.